# Проверка на наличие определенной папки

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне решить такую задачу. Задана основная папка. Нужно проверить, есть ли в этой папке подпапка с введенным названием. Если ее нет, то нужно создать и записывать туда некие файлы. Если она есть, то продолжать записывать в нее файлы. Не могу понять, где ошибка.

```
path = r'/home/anna/Документы/АВС/*'

if uname in path:
   print(uname, ' существует')
   f = open(uname, 'a')
   f.write(fileaudio)
   f.close()
if not uname in path:
   os.mkdir(uname)
   f = open(uname, 'a')
   f.write(fileaudio)
   f.close()введите сюда код
```

Comment: в данный момент у вас какая ошибка? не происходит проверка на наличие папки? не создается папка? не записываются файлы? нужно больше вводных данных

Comment: Сейчас вы проверяете наличие `uname` в строке(!) `path`. Чтобы проверить, есть ли папка с таким названием в папке по пути `path` нужно для начала эту папку открыть, используя `os.listdir(path)`, после чего проверить, что среди папок в полученном списке будет одна с названием `uname`. Или, что будет более адекватно, нужно просто использовать `os.path.isdir(path + uname)`

Comment: Если папка не существует, то выдает ошибку FileExistsError в строке os.mkdir. Если папка существует, то выдает ошибку IsADirectoryError в строке open(uname, 'a').

Comment: а как это вы хотите открыть папку `uname` как файл ? вам нужно внутри папки свои файлы делать..

Comment: Я хочу открыть папку uname как папку, а не файл.

Comment: `open(uname)` говорит об обратном

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если `path` - *основная папка*, а `folder_name` - *подпапка с введенным названием*:

```
import os

path = 'D:/*'
folder_name = 'my'
filename = 'my_file.txt'

try:
    folder_path = os.path.join(*path.split('/')[:-1], folder_name)
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

with open(os.path.join(folder_path, filename), 'a') as fout:
    fout.write('Hello')
```

Или можно так, чтобы не писать к каждому файлу полный путь:

```
try:
    folder_path = os.path.join(*path.split('/')[:-1], folder_name)
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
except FileExistsError:
    pass
finally: # <---
    os.chdir(folder_path) # <---

with open(filename, 'a') as fout: # <---
    fout.write('Hello')
```

Comment: я бы все же использовал модуль pathlib